# HTML5 Audio recording too large

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I managed to create a complete recorder using HTML5.
My problem is the **size of the WAV file** created, it's too large to be sent to my servers. I'm using the `exportWAV` function alot of users seem to be using.
This function creates a WAV file from the audio BLOB:

```
function encodeWAV(samples){
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
  var view = new DataView(buffer);

  writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
  view.setUint32(4, 32 + samples.length * 2, true);
  writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
  writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
  view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
  view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
  view.setUint16(22, 1, true);
  view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
  view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
  view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
  view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
  writeString(view, 36, 'data');
  view.setUint32(40, samples.length * 2, true);
  floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples);

  return view;
}
```

I was browsing through the alternatives, but none of them are really sufficient or simple enough:

- Zipping the file - Doesn't work well and has some security issues.
- Converting to MP3 - Makes the process much slower and complicated, also has security issues, and causes the sound to lose alot of quality.

My question is - Does the HTML5 getUserMedia export **only to .WAV files** ?
If there was a function, like `encodeWAV` I used, which is `encodeMP3` - That would be **perfect**.

What is the recommended way so solve such a problem?

I'd love to get a simple working example if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: "also has security issues"  What security issues are you referring to?  And, if you want to record something of a higher quality than MP3, you need lossless audio encoding.  Are you *sure* a high bitrate MP3 or Opus audio file is too poor of quality for your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the HTML5 getUserMedia export only to .WAV files ?

getUserMedia doesn't export anything at all.  getUserMedia only returns a MediaStream for some sort of audio/video capture.

This MediaStream is used in conjunction with the Web Audio API where you can access PCM samples.  WAV files typically contain raw PCM samples.  (WAV is a container format.  PCM is the sample format, and is the most popular way of encoding audio digitally.)

> Zipping the file - Doesn't work well and has some security issues.

It works just fine when you consider the constraints and has no inherent security issues.  In this case, you're getting a lossless compression of audio data.  Characteristics of something like that are compression that won't reduce the size by more than 15%-30% or so.

> Converting to MP3 - Makes the process much slower and complicated, also has security issues, and causes the sound to lose alot of quality.

You can encode as you record so slowness isn't a problem.  Complicated... maybe at first but not really once you've used it.  The issue here is that you're concerned about quality loss.

Unfortunately, you don't get to pick perfect quality and tiny size.  These are tradeoffs and there is no magic bullet.  Any lossy compression you use (like MP3, AAC, Opus, Vorbis) will reduce your data size considerably by removing part of the audio that we don't normally perceive.  The less bandwidth there is, the more artifacts occur from this process.  You have to decide between data size and quality.

If I might make a suggestion... Use the MediaRecorder API.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API  It's a very easy API to use.  You create a MediaRecorder, give it a stream, tell it to record, and then deal with the data it gives you in whatever way you wish.  Most browsers supporting the MediaRecorder API also support Opus for an audio codec, which provides good performance at most any bitrate.  You can choose the bitrate you want and know that you're getting about the best quality audio you can get for that amount of bandwidth.

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way is probably to use the [API already there in your browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) instead of rewriting it yourself with the poor tools we've got.

So to record an audio stream, [(https fiddle for chrome)](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnno2rdh/)

```js
// get our audio stream
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: true
}).then(setup);

function startRecording(stream) {
  let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  let chunks = []; // here we'll store all recorded chunks
  // every time a new chunk is available, store it
  recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => chunks.push(e.data);
  recorder.onstop = () => {
    let blob = new Blob(chunks);
    saveRecordedAudio(blob);
  };
  recorder.start();
  return recorder;
}

function saveRecordedAudio(blob) {
  // do whatever with this audio file e.g:
  // var form = new FormData();
  // form.append('file', blob, 'myaudio.ogg');
  // xhr.send(form)

  // for demo here, we'll just append a new audio with the recorded audio
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = new Audio(url);
  a.controls = true;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.onload = () => URL.revokeObjectURL(url);// better to always revoke blobURLs...
}

function setup(stream) {
  let btn = document.querySelector('button');
  let recording = false;
  var recorder; // weird bug in FF when using let...
  btn.onclick = (e) => {
    if (recording = !recording) {
      recorder = startRecording(stream);
    } else {
      recorder.stop();
    }
    e.target.textContent = (recording ? 'stop' : 'start') + ' recording';
  };
}
```

```html
<button>start recording</button>
```

This will record your stream as an OPUS/ogg, if you want wav, simply [do the conversion server side](https://linuxconfig.org/ffmpeg-audio-format-conversions#h2-2-ogg-to-wav).

Comment: What is streamNode ? I'm getting an error: streamNode is not defined

Comment: @KobyDouek `streamNode` is `aCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();` should have been defined when loadedmetadata fires, but moved its declaration to the top so it should work now. Note that in your case, it should be the stream returned by `getUserMedia`

Comment: In the code you wrote, what starts the recording? I need to start recording on a button event

Comment: ogg to wav? What benefit could you get (beside the extension and unless FLAC-ed)?

Comment: Also, in your code where is [revokeObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL)?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, wav may have more support across different softwares than ogg. You can also do ogg to mp3, just the chapter before in the link.
revokeObjectURL is not in this example because it is just an example, didn't wanted to add something that is not needed by OP (he won't use `createObjectURL` at first if all he needs is to upload the recorded file.) and since here it is created from a sandboxed iframe I don't even think the browser will keep it in memory.

Comment: @KobyDouek, `recorder.start()`is what starts the recorder... Have a look at my link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder and at this one : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder_API/Using_the_MediaRecorder_API

Comment: I'm trying to pass this through sox as it's already installed, but I get "sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `test.ogg': Input not an Ogg Opus audio stream"

Any one any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode mp3 so it would take less space...

`libmp3lame.js` is the tools for you...

Full article in [here](http://audior.ec/blog/recording-mp3-using-only-html5-and-javascript-recordmp3-js/) - how to record to mp3.

Comment: Thanks for the post, but like I wrote - I saw this solution. It only CONVERTS the file to MP3, which Makes the process much slower and complicated, also has security issues, and causes the sound to lose alot of quality

Comment: It converts recording in flight, not a file... but you can do nothing about size of wav, if you don't want to use compression.

Comment: It converts the WAV file after reading it as a file stream, after it was created. Testing this solution, there are alot of security issues and the file loses its quality (its basically turning it to mono)

Comment: that probably depends of lame library configuration... try changing the compression to lower